# ASP.NET Core 1.0: Azure: Razor View: System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode: Not working

Tags: asp.net-core, razor

I have an ASP.NET Core 1.0 website with some views. I am trying to decode an html-encoded string in my view as follows:
For example: I am trying to decode the string:
Rénaté Réno

```
@model PaymentHistory

@{    
    if(Model != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.CardholderName))
    {
        Model.CardholderName = System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(Model.CardholderName);
    }
}
```

This code works in test environment in my machine, but when I deployed it to Azure(staging website), it didn't work. Am I missing something? I am new to Azure and don't know much about navigating the portal; so I don't really know the azure hosting environment and don't know much about debugging tools. 
System.Net.dll is in the bin directory under site/wwwroot.

Any help is appreciated.
NH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up decoding it in the Controller, not the View.Trying to decode in the view is still not working.